# Simple bash script for backing up and deleting directories

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, backup

I have made this and surprise, it isn't working

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/test/backup

cp -a vaults backup/vaults-$(date +%d-%m-%y-%S)

find backup/vaults-* -mtime +5 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

I need it to backup directories and then delete all directories that are older than 5 days. It deletes everything and outputs stuff like this

```
find: `backup/vaults-27-02-17-41': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this kind of backup things using tar. Here's an example for your situation:

```
tar -czf /backup/vault-$(date -I).tar.gz vaults/*
find backup/ -type f -iname "*.tar.gz" -mtime +5 -delete
```

Here with `tar` command we get compressed backup archive with timestamp.
Then with `find` we only look for files ending with tar.gz in backup directory, then delete them if they are older than five days.

But if you cannot use tar and want to use cp and find. Then you did got it almost right already, but your find should be like this:

```
find backup/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname "vaults-*" -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Notice mindepth and maxdepth switches, with them having the value 1, find only lists the backup directories. Without them find will try to descend into the directory after it has executed the `rm` command thus resulting in an error like you had or it could also try to delete the parent directory. Also `rm` command must be executed with "-rf" options so that it will remove also directories which are not empty and won't try to ask anything while doing it.

You should also consider using [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) for this kind of backup. It would save you some storage space and it also handles deletion based on retention policy you can configure yourself.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answer. I cant compress it because it is 500GB+ . Also it has to be ready at any time  without waiting for anything.

Comment: Okay, maybe you should checkout rsnapshot? that could be a good solution. It does save you some storage space and it also manages deletion of data.

Comment: I updated my answer...

Comment: It does create directory, but deletes it right after + it outputs still same message : find: `backup/vaults-27-02-17-37': No such file or directory

Comment: Then there is something strange going on... Is the destination possibly a removable media?

Comment: No, the directory is created just for this purpose.

Comment: Oh... you need probably the prune options also to find command.. try to add "-prune" to it.

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Comment: Now it looks like it is doing what is supposed to do. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54411/discussion-between-radek-pulkrabek-and-stefanr).